# How to extend Neotree to open a file using hexl?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I'm trying to extend Neotree to open a file using hexl-mode with the shortcut C-c C-x. How would one do this?

I've tried to evaluate a key definition after the Neotree load where it uses my/neotree-hex to open a file path using neo-buffer--get-filename-current-line.

```
(defun my/neotree-hex
    (hexl-find-file neo-buffer--get-filename-current-line))
(with-eval-after-load 'neotree
  (define-key neotree-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-x")
    'my/neotree-hex))
```

Comment: move the `(with-eval-after-load ...)` to the top-level

Comment: @jenesaisquoi: it *is* at the top level - the indentation is misleading.

Comment: right, the defun isn't defined properly - it should be `(defun my/neotree-hex () ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least, you are missing the (empty) argument list in the function:

```
(defun my/neotree-hex ()
    (hexl-find-file neo-buffer--get-filename-current-line))
```

I don't know what `neo-buffer--get-filename-current-line` is: if it is a function, then you are not calling it correctly - in lisp, you call a function by enclosing the (name of the) function and its arguments in parens: `(func arg1 arg2 ...)`[1]; so if it *is* a function and it takes no arguments, then your function should probably look like this:

```
(defun my/neotree-hex ()
    (interactive)
    (hexl-find-file (neo-buffer--get-filename-current-line)))
```

In order to be able to bind it to a key, you have to make your function a [command](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/What-Is-a-Function.html#What-Is-a-Function), which means that you need to add the `(interactive)` form.

Disclaimer: I know nothing about `neotree`.

[1] You might want to read an introduction to lisp. One (specifically tailored to Emasc Lisp) is included with the emacs documentation, but is also [available online](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/eintr.html). Eventually, you will want to read the [Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/index.html). Calling a function is [covered in the Introduction](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Run-a-Program.html#Run-a-Program) and is [covered in detail in the Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Evaluation.html#Evaluation).

Comment: Thank you. The resulting code below is now working as intended.
    (defun my/neotree-hex ()
    (interactive)
    (hexl-find-file (neo-buffer--get-filename-current-line)))
    (with-eval-after-load 'neotree
    (define-key neotree-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-x")
    'my/neotree-hex))

I haven't had the time to look at Lisp in detail, but Emacs is very useful even without exhaustive Lisp knowledge. Still, thank you for the reading material at [1], it's on my to do list.